# Continuous delivery of a docker container to Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, bitbucket-pipelines

**Goal**:

I have an application based inside a docker container. I want to be able to use continuous integration for that with push to deploy using Bitbucket Pipelines to Google Cloud. I need access to an SQL database (MariaDB preferably), and some kind of caching system (be it memcache, redis, or something else).

**Problem**:

I'm entirely unsure of what services I need from said cloud provider to facilitate this as simply as possible, while still being cost effective. I looked into using Google's AppEngine, but I don't know if I'm doing something weird or odd, but for 1 vCPU w/ 1 GB of RAM and 10GB of storage, it was $55/month USD. Which is far more than I really want to pay. But I'm not even sure this is what I need for this. I don't need much power (these are very small apps, used by a very small amount of people). Also, again, not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but I was unable to find a caching solution with Google that wasn't insanely expensive (MemoryStore). Basically, I'm completely overwhelmed by the # of options, and am just looking for a cost effective / simple solution for continuous delivery of a docker application to Google Cloud

Comment: This question is opinion based and therefore not the best one for this site. First you need to pick your platform (you will not be deploying this to all 3 platforms) and then look for specific services. And then you will have specific programming questions.

Comment: @JleruOHeP Thanks for your comment. I've amended my question to focus on Google Cloud. But I'm unsure as to what services I would use for this, and that's what my question is really focusing on.

Answer (score -1):

Using the tools discussed [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery/) , you can set up an end-to-end continuous delivery pipeline covering code, build, test, deploy, and monitor phases of software development across multi-cloud, hybrid, or on-premise environment. Likely this is a way to start.